# execution a scala file with spark to read a kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stream, spark-streaming, avro

I'm trying to run a scala code to read a kafka topic but I'm still having this error msg. I would like also to know if there is any other method to run a scala code from file (I'm using spark-shell -i path/file.scala  and then KafkaConsumerAvro.main(Array()) is it the practical way to run a spark program ?  ).

```
scala> import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

scala>

scala>

scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala>

scala> import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.Schema

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

scala> object KafkaConsumerAvro {
     |     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     |
     |       val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
     |         .master("local")
     |         .appName("SparkByExample.com")
     |         .getOrCreate()
     |       spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
     |       val df = spark.readStream
     |         .format("kafka")
     |         .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
     |         .option("subscribe", "avro-topic")
     |         .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") // From starting
     |         .load()
     |       /*
     |        Prints Kafka schema with columns (topic, offset, partition e.t.c)
     |         */
     |       df.printSchema()
     |
     |   }
     | }
defined object KafkaConsumerAvro

scala> KafkaConsumerAvro.main(Array())
 WARN sql.SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:652)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
  at KafkaConsumerAvro$.main(<console>:64)
  ... 61 elided
```

I would like to print and know the schema of my avro data dynamically and effect a decoding from avro to a readable data then storage it in table on HUE  (knowing that in my data i have one column that is binary), Please any suggestion ?

Comment: based on [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), which is the guide that the message is suggesting to follow, at first glance your code looks ok. Are you trying to run the code from the scala REPL? Have you tried to run it using `sbt run` or from `spark-shell` as the guide suggests? Also the error message `Failed to find data source: kafka` sounds like there is an issue trying to consume messages from kafka. Where you able to connect to kafka and produce/consume messages there?

Comment: Take a look at "deploying" section of [this guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying). The error message suggests that Spark can't find `spark-sql-kafka` package